# What is the minimum pressure for a fluid to flow in a horizontal pipe of circular cross section as a function of dynamic viscosity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics

My question is relatively simple. Assume incompressible, laminar flow.

Will fluid continue to flow through a pipe if I calculate that a 5 psi pressure drop occurs across the pipe using either the Darcy-Weisbach/Hagen-Poiseuille equation but my pressure source only supplies 4 psi? I would assume that it would **not** continue to flow because there is now sufficient resistance in the pipe to prevent flow.

Comment: Flow will stop only if the *load* is greater than the pressure source.

Comment: You can have the volume flux rate arbitrarily low but non-zero (in Hagen-Poiseuille for example)... Why would the flow stop at a low but non-zero externally provided pressure difference that is not balanced by anything?

Comment: For this particular pipe there is a 5 psi drop that is calculated but the pressure source is at 4 psi. Wouldn't the pressure at the source need to be at least 5 psi or greater for fluid to flow through this pipe?

Comment: That equation depends on the flow rate though! If the external pressure is lower, the flow rate is lower, and the pressure drop across the pipe is lower. All are proportional to eachother, so it remains true that for an arbitrarily small external pressure, the pressure drop due to viscosity is arbitrarily small because the flow rate is arbitrarily low (but not zero)

Comment: How did you calculate the pressure drop? Did you assume a certain value for the flow rate?

Comment: Yes, I see my faulty, circular thinking on this. What I am really after is a clear mental model for overcoming flow resistance. Based on the equations above for an arbitrarily small pressure there will be some amount of volumetric flow. However, in a real pipe there is a minimum pressure for flow to start to occur. Especially if the source pressure is low, the diameter of pipe is small, the length of the pipe is long and the viscosity is high. I am guessing the model is incomplete and there is additional resistance that would prevent the flow.